# Find the number of distinguishable arrangements.

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

If $r_1$ indistinguishable things of one kind and $r_2$ indistinguishable things of a second kind are placed into $n$ cells, find the number of distinguishable arrangements.

My answer for this question is that ${r_1+r_2 + n -1 \choose n-1}{r_1 + r_2 \choose r_1}$ because we need to consider all arrangements $r_1, r_2$ and cells. Thus, after we choose the arrangement of cells, we choose $r_1$ (or $r_2$) from $r_1 +r_2$. However, the solution is ${r_1 + n -1 \choose r_1}{r_2 + n - 1 \choose r_2}$, and I don't think that this is the same. Could you explain how to derive this solution? Why my logic is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your solution assumes that the objects in each cell are ordered, which is not true: $\binom{r_1+r_2+n-1}{n-1}$ is the number of ways to assign $r_1+r_2$ objects to the cells, $\binom{r_1+r_2}{r_1}$ is the number of ways to assign kinds to them *but with the false assumption that there is order in each cell*. Because of the lack of order, the two kinds can be considered independently, leading to the correct result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't understand the statement "Because of the lack of order, the two kinds can be considered independently". Could you elaborate this a bit please?

Comment: @shk910 It doesn't matter whether we put one kind in first or the other. The only relevant numbers are the counts of each kind in each cell. We might as well put all of one kind in first, then all of the other kind.

Comment: @shk910 If there are to be 2 reds and 1 green in box 1, your method counts the 3 different ways of assigning those colors to those three balls as different, whereas they should count as the same. So you are overcounting. Try it for only one cell, two reds and one green.... there's only one way to do it but you get an answer of 3.